# Is it possible for users to upload to google cloud storage?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I'd like to create an object, give my users an upload url, and let them upload data. The resulting object must be public-readable. Is this possible with google cloud storage? If so, is it possible through google app engine, and where can I find documentation and/or examples for doing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create an upload url using the blobstore service. See the [create_upload_url](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/functions#create_upload_url) function.

To make the object publicly accessible you may need to play with the acls of the bucket.

See also the [Cloud Storage Overview](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlestorage/overview).

Answer (score 12):

To have a user upload directly to Google Cloud Storage, you can use the [Signed URLs](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/accesscontrol#Signed-URLs) feature. This allows you to grant access to issue a PUT request to an object to a single user.

If you're using Python, there is a [python example demonstrating signed URLs](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/storage-signedurls-python).

Answer (score 0):

Another option to upload directly to Google Cloud Storage is [Resumable URLs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/upload#resumable).

If your object is big, such as a video, you can upload it in chunks this way. If the upload fails (e.g. client loses internet connection), you can resume from where you left off and not have to have the user start over again. Plus you save some money by not having to restart that upload.

However if your media is small, just use Signed URLs.